# open pdf from Menu List in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf

I am a neophyte programmer who was right on the cusp of his answer over here at

[Loading a pdf file in Visual Basic Windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233619/loading-a-pdf-file-in-visual-basic-windows-form?answertab=active#tab-top)

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get in touch with the person whom I thought gave the best answer, so forgive me if this answer is inapropes...

I would like to add .pdf files to my programme, so that the user can simply read directly upon clicking the menu item.

I have the files "Benutzerhandbuch Info 2 Projekt.pdf" and "Produktbeschreibung Info II Projekt.pdf" ready to go, but don't know where I should save them.

I've already got Adobe installed on my machine and in  my toolbox.

GojiraDeMonstah answered with what I think is the best solution (??) but I couldn't ask any further q's as it is against policy and I don't have enough cred 'cause I'm new.

Q* - where should I save the file so that VB can see it?
Q* - once the programming is complete, I will then burn this to CD and give it to Prof as a kind of "Product", but if I link a pdf file saved on my computer, then how will my prof see the file?

Sorry if these questions sound really basic, but I don't even know what to search for besides what I have already done. I really do need a bit of hand-holding here. I wish I could upload pics, because it would make my question easier to understand. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This page shows the special directories [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a WebBrowser Control in your WinForm, then:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("c:\test.pdf")
```

Comment: Q* - where should I save the file so that VB can see it? 
Q* - but if I link a pdf file saved on my computer, then how will my prof see the file?

Comment: Embed the pdf file(s) as resources in your project. See  [this link](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_embedded_resources.html) that also provides the method to open a stream attached to a resource file data. Use a FileStream to write to a temporary pdf file the data read from the input stream. You may write the .pdf file on the .exe directory or on the windows temporary folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
Public Class Benutzerhandbuch

Private Sub Benutzerhandbuch_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e     As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub AxWebBrowser1_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AxWebBrowser1.Enter
    AxWebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\FilenamePath\Filename.pdf")
End Sub
End Class
```

Special thanks to all who contributed.
Logan